# Moving a part of xaml file to another xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

In my project, I have XAML file like this:

```
<Grid Margin="50,0,0,0">
   //Huge amount of code goes here
</Grid>
```

It is very difficult to go through all the code in `Grid` while designing. Can I move all the code to a separate XAML file file and in in this `Grid` content i will call that XAML file??

```
<Grid Margin="50,0,0,0">
    //call xaml file here
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a UserControl; assume the "Huge amount of code" is sth like this:

```
<Border Name="yourBorder">
      //Other Xamls
</Border>
```

Now you create a new UserControl an put this Border in it

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
 <Border Name="yourBorder">
      //Other Xamls
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

You can use `UserControl1` in other Xamls. You should add `xmlns:wp="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"` to your Xaml. For example if you want to use it in a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wp="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUpper"     //This is what I mentioned
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <wp:UserControl1 />    // You call it using this format
</SatckPanel>
```